# Google Scripts UI: Prompt error when shared

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on creating a Sidebar to assist a user in filling out a multiple sheet spreadsheet. So far, I have my HTML written for the sidebar and I create a few links that will prompt the user for text and then fill in the proper cell on the proper sheet. 
On the HTML side I have this piece:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="google.script.run.withUserObject(this).addExcuse(<?= ua[x] ?>, <?= l_name.toUpperCase() ?>)">
```

This will call the function `addExcuse(sheetName, last_name)`. The code for `addExcuse()` is as follows:

```
function addExcuse(x, name) {
 var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
 var response = ui.prompt("Enter your excuse for " + x);
 ...
}
```

The `...` replaces the code that loads the proper sheet, finds the right cell and changes its value.
My problem is that when I (the spreadsheet owner) run this script - everything works fine. The HTML properly links and the proper function is called, the prompt is displayed and the rest of the code abbreviated with the `...` works fine.
When a user shared on this spreadsheet and set with Edit permissions clicks on one of the links in the sidebar - nothing happens. There is not even a prompt displayed asking for the text.

What could the issue be here? 
This script is running as a bound-script to this spreadsheet. There is sheet protection and such but, I don't believe the server-side function is ever called. 
Since everything works for me and not for anyone else, could this be a authorization issue? If so, how could I get this to run properly?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, Apps Scripts have to be installed for every user independently. Here's how to publish an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/publish?hl=en).

Comment: So even though I own the sheet, the shared users must also install the script? There are things running as an Event Trigger that do work. Is that because of the fact that event triggers run as the user who created them?